# Why use int in enum declaration?

Tags: c#, enums

What's the point of using **: int** in the enum declaration as following?

```
public enum AAType : int
{
    Folder = 0,    
    File = 1,   
    Link = 2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default backing type of `enum` is `int`. You can change the backing type to something else, like `short` or `long`. Specifying `int` is probably just for clarity.

Comment: is there any other data type that can be the backing type of enum?

Comment: Any of the integral types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w(v=VS.80).aspx) except char

Answer (score 7):

The default underlying type of an `enum` is `int`, so by specifying it explicitly you only (perhaps) gain in clarity, but the behavior's just the same as if `: int` was omitted.

Answer (score -3):

The fact that an Enum is a specialized Int you can use bytes for each Enum value (Apple = 1, Pear = 2, Orange = 4) and then you can pass the Enums in Piped and determine what to do based on the byte value (look at Reflection.BindingFlags, etc).

Comment: You can implement flags (which is what I think you're trying to describe) using backing types other than int.